# error using `purrr::map` and `openxlsx` package - A worksheet by the name 'test1' already exists! Sheet names must be unique case-insensitive

Tags: r, function, purrr, openxlsx

I have written some functions where I basically want to loop through a few times.

Each time I run the "test_fun" function I want to create a new workbook, run another function (that basically adds worksheets to that workbook and some data) and then save the workbook.

However, I always get the following error:

```
<error/purrr_error_indexed>
Error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `addWorksheet()`:
! A worksheet by the name 'test1' already exists! Sheet names must be unique case-insensitive.
---
Backtrace:
     ▆
  1. └─purrr::map(.x = c("x1", "x2", "x3"), .f = ~test_fun(abc = .x, my_names = my_names))
  2.   └─purrr:::map_("list", .x, .f, ..., .progress = .progress)
  3.     ├─purrr:::with_indexed_errors(...)
  4.     │ └─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
  5.     ├─purrr:::call_with_cleanup(...)
  6.     └─global .f(.x[[i]], ...)
  7.       └─global test_fun(abc = .x, my_names = my_names)
  8.         └─purrr::map(...)
  9.           └─purrr:::map_("list", .x, .f, ..., .progress = .progress)
 10.             ├─purrr:::with_indexed_errors(...)
 11.             │ └─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
 12.             ├─purrr:::call_with_cleanup(...)
 13.             └─.f(.x[[i]], ...)
 14.               └─global test_fun_inner(xyz = my_names[[.x]], mtcars, .x)
 15.                 └─openxlsx::addWorksheet(wb_output, sheetName = xyz)
 16.                   └─base::stop(paste0("A worksheet by the name '", sheetName, "' already exists! Sheet names must be unique case-insensitive."))
```

When I run my code manually (i.e. manually creating the objects to loop through and send run the code within the functions manually, I'm not getting any error).

Here's some code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(openxlsx)

test_fun_inner <- function(xyz, data, column)
{
  addWorksheet(wb_output, sheetName = xyz)
  writeData(wb = wb_output,
            sheet = xyz,
            x = data[[column]])
}

test_fun <- function(abc, my_names)
{
  # Create Workbook
  wb_output <- createWorkbook()
  
  # loop through all sheets
  map(.x = 1:2,
      .f = ~test_fun_inner(xyz = my_names[[.x]], mtcars, .x))
  
  # save Excel file
  saveWorkbook(wb        = wb_output,
               file      = paste0(abc, ".xlsx"),
               overwrite = TRUE)
}

my_names <- list("test1", "test2")

map(.x = c("x1", "x2", "x3"),
    .f = ~test_fun(abc = .x,
                   my_names = my_names))
```

EDIT:

When I manually delete the `wb_output` object from the environment and then run the code again, I'm getting another error:

```
Error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `addWorksheet()`:
! object 'wb_output' not found
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have wb_output defined for test_fun_inner.

```
test_fun_inner <- function(wb_output, xyz, data, column)
{
  addWorksheet(wb_output, sheetName = xyz)
  writeData(wb = wb_output,
            sheet = xyz,
            x = data[[column]])
}

test_fun <- function(abc, my_names)
{
  # Create Workbook
  wb_output <- createWorkbook()
  
  # loop through all sheets
  map(.x = 1:2,
      .f = ~test_fun_inner(wb_output, xyz = my_names[[.x]], mtcars, .x))
  
  # save Excel file
  saveWorkbook(wb        = wb_output,
               file      = paste0(abc, ".xlsx"),
               overwrite = TRUE)
}
```

Comment: Yes, that‘s what I finally als figured out, but it still confuses me, because I thought that if a function doesn‘t define an argument, it will take it from the parent environment, no?

Comment: Like in this example; `x <- 1

fun <- function(y)
{
  print(x + y)
}

fun(2)`

Comment: See the explanation here. https://community.rstudio.com/t/confused-about-this-purrr-map-situation/90558/3